# Magento - Hide Layered Navigation Attribute if only 1 available

Tags: magento, attributes, layered-navigation

My store has numerous attributes in my layered navigation to allow customers to refine the product views/searches. On some of my categories i only have 1 attribute present.
For example one of my categories - `women > accessories > belts`

has:

```
- 1 price option ($10.00 and above)
- 3 colour options (brown, tan, black)
- 1 brand option (Levi's)
```

How can I hide any filters that only have 1 value present. So in this case instead of the above i would only want:

```
- 3 colour options (brown, tan, black)
```

to show in the layered navigation

Answer (score 0):

Replace in `root/app/design/frontent/<package>/<theme>/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml` in 49th row:

```
<?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
```

With

```
<?php if($_filter->getItemsCount() && $_filter->getItemsCount()>1): ?>
```